# Add a gaussian noise layer between pretrained network layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I would like to add a gaussian layer model to a pretrained vgg16 network (after convolutional layer 1) and have the noisy layer active when I pass the images (I would like to obtain activation of layers after passing through a noise layer during inference phase).

I have managed to compile a 'new' model which has the gaussian layer added to it. I also have code for passing images and obtaining activations to them (using model.predict(img)). My problem is that now when I am passing the images through the gaussian noise layer the activation does not change from passing through the layer prior. I have read that gaussian noise layers are usually used in training (not testing - which is relevant for me), but I've also read that you can 'trick' a layer into believing you are in a training state and still have the gaussian noise active. I don't know how to practically implement this.

Here I am creating my new model with gaussian noise layer:

```
# load the model
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
# summarize the model
model.summary()
# loop over layers and add noise - create a new model
for i in range(1,len(model.layers)): # loop over all layers
    #print ('Working on '+layer_names[i])
    layer1 = model.layers[i]
    if i==1: # adding the noise
        noise = GaussianNoise(0.85)
        x = noise(layer1.output)
    if i<len(model.layers)-1: # reconnecting the layers
        layer2 = model.layers[i+1]
        x = layer2(x) 
    if i==len(model.layers)-1:
        predictors = x # this is the last layer
# Create a new model 
model2 = Model(input=model.input, output=predictors)
model2.summary()
```

Here is an example of how I would like to obtain activation of all layers (including Gaussian layer).

```
layer_names = ['block1_conv1',model2.layers[2].name,'block1_conv2','block2_conv1','block2_conv2','block3_conv1','block3_conv2','block3_conv3',\
               'block4_conv1','block4_conv2','block4_conv3','block5_conv1','block5_conv2','block5_conv3','fc1','fc2','predictions'];
for i in range(1,len(layer_names)): # loop over all layers
    print ('Working on '+layer_names[i])
    layer_name = layer_names[i]
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model2.input,outputs=model2.get_layer(layer_name).output)
    # load the image with the required shape
    img = image.load_img('test.BMP', target_size=(224,224)) # plot with img
    # convert the image to an array
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    # expand dimensions so that it represents a single 'sample'
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    # prepare the image (e.g. scale pixel values for the vgg)
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    # Now get the activations to this image
    intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(img)
```

The output (intermediate_output) should be different after receiving output from block1_cov1 layer vs. gaussian_noise layer, but it isn't. I guess that's because the Gaussian noise layer is not active, but I don't know how to change that. I know my code is suboptimal (just starting to work with Keras), but any help on how to get a noise to a pretrained network and let it 'propagate' through a network would be highly appreciated.